# Counterpart of Heroku dynos or workers on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, heroku

I am looking for an AWS instance that will allow me to run a simple python script made with a flask that runs constantly in an infinite loop.

The instance must be created and configured via an API call from the main web page with its own database in postgres.

Example:

Client1 -> Go to the web page and create his own instance -> The web page calls the AWS API -> AWS creates an instance1 for client1 which is constantly running.

Note: I am looking for a cheaper service for it. It may be something between the EC2 instance and the Lambda function (the Labmda function doesn't work because it needs to be autonomous).
If the Python instance script fails for any reason, it should restart automatically.
Also the client1 has the option to turn the script off and on whenever he wants.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk is the equivalent of Heroku.

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/